# jQuery triggers out event even though it should be still in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a rather awkward problem. I register two event handlers, one for `mouseenter` and one for `mouseout` for the `li` elements on the page. It has multiple `div` areas inside it. When I leave the `li` element it calls the `out` handler, which is ok. What is not ok is that the `out` handler is also triggered when I leave a `div` inside that `li`.

Below is an image that illustrates it. The blue area is the `li` element which I register an `enter` and `out` event for.
[image]

I tried to register handlers on the inner `divs` that would stop the propagation but it only results in the triggering of the `out` handler when I enter those inner divs.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: please post your code... We can't do anything with a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mouseleave` instead of mouseout. `Mouseout` triggers everytime your mouse is going off from exactly atop of the target. So when you enter the `divs`, your mouse goes out of the `li` and on the div. But it is still inside the `LI` of course, using mouseleave will make it work.

From JQuery doc:

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.